# Best approach of passing 2 columns in Spring JSP Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jsp

Seeking advise on what can be the best approach of selecting 2 columns (ID, NAME) from a table and passing them to the JSP page. JSP page will be displaying one of the column (NAME) as href and on clicking will be returning another column (ID) value to the Spring MVC.

**Technologies are:** Spring MVC, Hibernate, JSP, JSTL

Employee table has lot of column along with columns that has *@OneToOne* and *@OneToMany* relationship with another tables.

**Employee** - ID, NAME, age, gender, height, weight, Address (OneToMany), Phone (OneToMany), FavouriteColor (OneToOne)

**Approach 1:** Select all columns of the Employee class. Problem with this approach is that unnecessary whole data including Address, Phone table will be selected from the database. Due to OneToMany relationship, there will be multiple ID and NAME returned and I have to write logic in JSP to avoid displaying duplicate results.

**Approach 2:** Create a another class (EmployeeTrim) that has only 2 columns (ID and class). Problem is of maintaining 2 classes doing same functionality.

**Approach 3:** Select only 2 columns from the Employee class. Pass them to JSP as Map. In JSP display the NAME with href of ID. I am not sure how JSP part can be implemented.

**Approach 4:** Select only 2 column from Employee class and pass them as 2 different model's to the JSP. This can be done easily but I believe that approach 3 would be better if JSP part can be implementable.

Kindly suggest which approach from above can be implemented or is there any other other method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 2 is the best performing solution. You shouldn't select entities when you are only interested in projections.

[Using SQL projection to a DTO result object](http://relation.to/2133.lace) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still working on its implementation and will come back on this.